# Understanding directory linkage in php

Tags: php

I need some help in understanding how directory paths and file linking works. I am testing this on a local server.

If I have the following files in the **ROOT Directory**:
- **includes [folder]**
-- **index.php [php file inside includes folder]**
- **adm [folder]**
  -- **constant.php [php file inside adm folder]**

I want to require "constant.php" inside the "index.php", how can I do that?

*Another confusion is that what is the difference between real path and relative path in PHP?*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use require statement in the "index.php", you can write as below.

**require "../adm/constant.php";**

As above, we use relative path. Real path means full path.

If ROOT Directory is /var/www/html/, then you can use as below.

**require "/var/www/html/adm/constant.php";**

This is real path.

I recommend relative path because site path can be changed, so real path will cause error.

See http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/ for understanding relative path more detail.